# Cannot set excluded field in ModelForm in Django 1.4

Tags: django, django-forms

I am trying to create a form for a model, and exclude one of the fields as I'm getting it in the url.

Based on the documentation for excluded fields in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/forms/modelforms/ I should be able to do the following:

```
class Activity:
    ....

class ActivityGoal(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    value = models.IntegerField()
    activity = models.ForeignKey(Activity)

class ActivityGoalForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ActivityGoal
        exclude = ('activity',)

....
activity = Activity.objects.get(id=id)
form = ActivityGoalForm(request.POST, activity=activity)
```

I'm setting the excluded field while instantiating the form, but I'm getting he following error:

```
__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'activity'
```

This is pretty much straight out of the sample code in the docs so not sure what I'm missing there. Any help would be appreciated before I resort to hand-crafting my form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the `activity` field is excluded, you cannot set it to instantiate forms. You need to set it differently.

Something like this:

```
activity = Activity.objects.get(id=id)
form = ActivityGoalForm(request.POST)
if form.is_valid():
    #use commit = false, set other excluded fields, and then save object
    obj = form.save(commit=False)
    obj.activity = activity
    obj.save()
```

Comment: Indeed works like this, but is different from the way it is documented. Thanks for the ultrafast response :)